# Changing direction of gravity

Tags: game-maker

I'd like to allow the player to change the direction of gravity in [gamemaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GameMaker:_Studio) (free version).  Once the player presses Space I want to add 90 degrees to whatever the current direction of gravity is.

To check if it is something related to my keybinds I have assigned a command to print something to the console once the Space key was pressed.  It seemed to work fine.

I am not very skilled yet, and I've tried to find tutorials on changing the gravity.  Either they are not clear enough or they just explain how to set normal gravity.

- I have tried using the set variable function with [gravity_direction](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/movement/gravity_direction.html)
- I have also tried using the set gravity function, but that doesn't seem to work for me either.
- I have set the gravity at this location: `rightclick object_player > properties > physics tab > Gravity X: 0.0 | Gravity Y: 30.0`
- I have tried setting the gravity manually in a create event with the variables: `gravity_direction: 270 gravity: 30` *(Removed the settings at the object properties first)*
- I have tried putting a set gravity function in a create element by itself to set the standard gravity.

For some reason I float upwards, in the last two cases.

Comment: 1. Change free version to standart version (its free)

Comment: 2. If you are using a physics engine, then it will replace all object parameters like `gravity_direction`, `speed`, etc (it will be ignored). In this case you need use `physics_*` and `phy_*` functions, like `physics_world_gravity`

Comment: Small example of using the built-in physics (press Space for change gravity) https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmm28v01lo1conz/gravity_change.gmz?dl=0 and more info about GMS physics see in tech blog http://yoyogames.com/tech_blog/83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you're not using the Physics Engine** *(you'd know if you were)*, then you can use the paired variables `gravity` and `gravity_direction`.

The `gravity` variable controls the magnitude of the gravity. Setting it to 1 is like having gravity be 1px/s<sup>2</sup>.

Typically I use variables lower than 10 for the `gravity` variable.

The `gravity_direction` variable controls the direction of the gravity. It ranges from 0 to 360, where the most used values are 0 (Right), 90 (Up), 180 (Left), and 270 (Down).

If you want gravity to change 90 degrees to the right (Clockwise), use `gravity_direction += 90`. If you want gravity to change 90 degrees to the left (Counter/Anti-Clockwise), use `gravity_direction -= 90`.

Just a word of warning, gravity is applied *after the End Step Event*, so if you're finding your character stuck in walls or having weird collision issues, you might want to implement your own gravity in the Begin Step or Step Event (I usually use the Step Event).

**If you're using the Physics Engine**, then the `gravity` and `gravity_direction` variables won't work. You'll need to use the [physics_world_gravity(x, y)](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/physics/the%20physics%20world/physics_world_gravity.html) function. Here, `x` controls the horizontal gravity, and `y` controls the vertical gravity.

So, if you wanted normal gravity, you'd use `physics_world_gravity(0, 32)`, or whatever value for `y` that you wanted.

Unfortunately there's no functions for determining the current gravity, so you'll have to make your own:

```
global.gravity_x = 0;
global.gravity_y = 32;

physics_world_gravity(global.gravity_x, global.gravity_y);
```

Typically when I'm using this system, I like to convert to old one, where there's a manitude (`gravity`) and direction (`gravity_direction`). So instead, I'd do this:

```
global.phys_gravity_force = 32;
global.phys_gravity_direction = 270; // Down

global.phys_gravity_x = lengthdir_x(global.phys_gravity_force, global.phys_gravity_direction);
global.phys_gravity_y = lengthdir_y(global.phys_gravity_force, global.phys_gravity_direction);

physics_world_gravity(global.phys_gravity_x, global.phys_gravity_x);
```

Every time you wanted to change the gravity of the world, you'd need to use all of the code in one of the two examples above. In my opinion, the second is easier, and all you would need to change each time would be the `global.phys_gravity_direction` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Tedisvet!
This is a relatively simple question for me, so I will go ahead and answer.

So, every time you press space, you want to add 90 degrees to the gravity direction. All you need to do is open the object you want the gravity to apply to, add a 'space pressed' event and in code, write

```
gravity_direction += 90;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

//If your pressing space bar and the worlds gravity is pulling you down at 30 metres per second squared then change gravity to pulling you to the left.

```
if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space) || physics_world_gravity(0, 30)) 
{
   physics_world_gravity(-30, 0);
}


if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space) || physics_world_gravity(-30, 0)) 
{
   physics_world_gravity(0, -30);
}


if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space) || physics_world_gravity(0, -30)) 
{
   physics_world_gravity(30, 0); 
}


if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space) || physics_world_gravity(30, 0)) 
{
   physics_world_gravity(0, 30); 
}
```

Keep in mind the room must have physics enabled. You could also change these numbers to change the direction of the gravity rotation. The one here is going to work clockwise.
I hope this helps.